# jQuery popup Close button missing

Tags: jquery, button, popup

I have a script to auto open and auto close a jQuery window. However, the `X` doesn't show up. I see the circular button, but it is missing the big `X` in the middle.

**Code:**

```js
$(function() {
  var popup = $('#test_popup');
  popup.popup();
  //popup.popup('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    popup.popup('open');
  }, 2000);

  $(document).on('popupafteropen', '.ui-popup', function() {
    var popup = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      //popup.popup('close');
      popup.hide();
    }, 10000);
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="test_popup" data-position-to="window">
  <p>
    <img src="namechange.png" /> <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-  
right">Close</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I was not calling the correct CSS, it works fine now.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"
```